# Split a javascript Javascript project in multiple package using webpack ou npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, redux

I'm trying to build an application that have to run on Windows(PC), Android and iOS.

For this, I will use Electron (for Windows) and React Native (for mobile plateforms). Both will be built with React and Redux. This way, I will be able to implement the logic in Redux reducers and middlewares and use them in both projects.

From now, I have done a POC for the Electron app using webpack. The reducers are currently directly in the app code. I want to extract the Redux relative code in a seperate package to allow me using it in a the React Native project.

I can make an npm package for my Redux module containing the reducers and the middlwares but this way, when I will compile my application, webpack will not compile my seperate package, it will use the precompiled version.

So What I want is to be able to make a separate package but still compile it at application compile time (because it is still in developpement and the dev is very closely related to main application dev).

Do I have to do it only with npm or with webpack as well ?

I'm pretty new to the Javascript dev stack.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have different ways to handle that problem.

1. You can use NPM package. But in code of package, you will store not only original source code, but compiled code too. I mean before publish that package, you'll need to compile it in normal ES5 code.
2. I think you can use submodule system provided by Git. You should have separate repository with common code of your reducers. And in each project (Electron, RN, etc.), you will have a directory with git submodule. Webpack should compile code in that directory normally without any problems.

UPD:

About submodules you can read nice article here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules#Starting-with-Submodules

In few words, in project it will looks like:

```
cd yourProjectFolder
git submodule add https://github.com/TalAter/awesome-service-workers submoduleDirectoryName
```

It will clone repository to your project, and create `.gitmodules` file. Code from submodule will not exists in current project repository. In remote repository it will contain only link to submodule, but on your machine, you will have full code and you will be able to compile it.

Comment: I'm interesting with the second solution, have you an example link ? Because I can't see How to acheive that

Comment: @steppfox I have found the `npm link` command that is, for me, simpler to setup and to use. I will accept your answer when my edit will be accepted since it's the solution I have used.